# Another problem about max values of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ be a function that is continuous on a closed bounded region $R$ and analytic and not constant throughout the interior of $R$. Prove that the component function $u(x,y)$ has a minimum value in $R$ which occurs on the boundary of $R$ and never in the interior. Hint: Consider $g(z)=1/f(z)$
Approach we have two results

Theorem: If a function $f$ is analytic and not constant in a given domain D, then $|f(z)|$ has no maximum value in $D$. That is, there is no point $z_0$ in the domain such that $|f(z)| \leq |f(z_0)|$ for all points $z$ in it.

Corollary: Suppose that a function f is continuous on a closed bounded region $R$ and that it is analytic and not constant in the interior of $R$. Then the maximum value of $|f(z)|$ in $R$, which is always reached, occurs somewhere on the boundary of $R$ and never in the interior

Approach: Maybe if we show that $v(x,y)$ is analytic and not constant throughout  R, we can show that $U(x,y)$ has a max value not inside R, but on it's boundary.